# Python, comparing dataframe rows, adding new column - Truth Value Error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, valueerror

I am quite new to Python, and somewhat stuck here.

I just want to compare floats with a previous or forward row in a dataframe, and mark a new column accordingly. FWIW, I have 6000 rows to compare. I need to output a string or int as the result.

My Python code:

```
for row in df_an:

    x = df_an['mid_h'].shift(1)
    y = df_an['mid_h']

    if y > x:
        df_an['bar_type'] = 1
```

I get the error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

The x and y variables are generated, but apparently things go wrong with the  `if y > x:` statement.

Any advice much appreciated.

**A different approach...**

I managed to implement the suggested .gt operator.

```
df_an.loc[df_an.mid_h.gt(df_an.mid_h.shift()) &\
          df_an.mid_l.gt(df_an.mid_l.shift()), "bar_type"] = UP
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of row; you basically shifting whole row then comparing; try this once;

```
df_an = pd.DataFrame({"mid_h":[1,3,5,7,7,5,3]}) 

df_an['bar_type'] = df_an.mid_h.gt(df_an.mid_h.shift())

# Output

   mid_h  bar_type
0      1     False
1      3      True
2      5      True
3      7      True
4      7     False
5      5     False
6      3     False
```

Comment: Thank you. Though I couldn't get an output other than True of False, which I suspect is down to my lack of knowledge about .gt in pandas.

Comment: Even I also got know about .gt lately :)... Thanks to SO... anyways... you can explore the same & maybe combine with .lt (less than) or .eq (equal) to make your outcome more generic...

Comment: Apologies, I failed to explain, I need to output a string or int, rather than a bool. I edited my original question to reflect this. I couldn't see on pandas docs if .gt will output a str on int. I think I have found an alternative solution now though. Thanks again.

Comment: I eventually managed to implement your suggested .gt operator. df_an.loc[df_an.mid_h.gt(df_an.mid_h.shift()) &\
          df_an.mid_l.gt(df_an.mid_l.shift()), "bar_type"] = UP
It's tough being a newbie, but I'm winning slowly. Thanks.